# Проблема с Transitions

Tags: android, android-layout, transition

Нужно реализовать вот такой эффект.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но мне нужно не совсем так:

Верхняя часть 40%, нижняя - 60% высоты экрана. Между этими `Layout` находится `FAB`. При нажатии на него он перемещается в центр нижней части экрана, затем из центра появляется эффект `ripple` с помощью `createCircularReveal()`. И я начал делать

**XML**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

                <LinearLayout
                          android:id="@+id/viewPh"
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="match_parent"
                          android:layout_weight="0.4"
                          android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
                          android:orientation="horizontal"/>

                <FrameLayout
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_weight="0.6"
                          android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                          android:id="@+id/viewMed"
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="match_parent"
                          android:background="#d45d1e"
                          />



                </FrameLayout>

      </LinearLayout>

      <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/scene_root"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/viewPh"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <include layout="@layout/scene1"/>

      </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**scene1**

```
<FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/container"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/fabscenefab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="startfab"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                app:backgroundTint="#d45d1e"
                android:src="@drawable/play"
      />

</FrameLayout>
```

**scene2**

```
<FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/container"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/fabscenefab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="end"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                app:backgroundTint="#d45d1e"
                android:src="@drawable/pause"
      />

</FrameLayout>
```

**JAVA**

```
public class FABScene extends AppCompatActivity {
private LinearLayout shape;
private Scene scene1, scene2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fabscene);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    shape = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.viewMed);
    shape.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra("title"));
    ViewGroup sceneRoot = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.scene_root);                   
    scene1 = Scene.getSceneForLayout(sceneRoot, R.layout.scene1, this);
    scene2 = Scene.getSceneForLayout(sceneRoot, R.layout.scene2, this);    

    }

public void end(View v){
        Animator animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(shape,shape.getWidth()/2,shape.getHeight()/2,(float) Math.hypot(shape.getWidth(), shape.getHeight()),0);
                animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                animator.setDuration(1400);
                animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter(){
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator a){
                        shape.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        TransitionSet set = new TransitionSet();
                        set.addTransition(new ChangeBounds());                                                         
                        set.setDuration(3000); 
                        set.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); 
                        TransitionManager.go(scene1, set);

                    }
                });
                animator.start();
}

public void startfab(View v){
    TransitionSet set = new TransitionSet();
    set.addTransition(new ChangeBounds());                                                         
    set.setDuration(3000); 
    set.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); 
    set.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener(){

            @Override
            public void onTransitionStart(Transition p1)
            {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTransitionEnd(Transition p1)
            {
                Animator animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(shape,shape.getWidth()/2,shape.getHeight()/2,0,(float) Math.hypot(shape.getWidth(), shape.getHeight()));
                shape.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                animator.setDuration(1400);
                animator.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionCancel(Transition p1)
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionPause(Transition p1)
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionResume(Transition p1)
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
            }


        });
    TransitionManager.go(scene2, set);

}
}
```

Не получается сделать, чтобы FAB была между двумя `layout` и перемещался на вторую сцену. Если поменять атрибуты высоты и ширины у `FrameLayout` (в котором первая сцена) на `match_parent`, то анимации происходят, но `FAB` находится в верхнем левом углу экрана. Что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы FloatingActionButton прикрепить к другой вью, надо использовать CoordinatorLayout и аттрибут app:layout_anchor. Как-то так:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Но, видимо, в этом случае сценой должен быть весь CoordinatorLayout.